# C# "Unable to cast objectt of type to another type. Exception thrown

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am getting an exception when I cast an object and checking if the property is null.

Here is my code

```
bool isValid = ((MyCustomViewModel)obj.AddressObject).BusinessAddress != null
```

is there a better way to check if obj.AddressObject has a BusinessAddress object?

I also tried

```
bool isValid = obj.AddressObject.BusinessAddress != null
```

but I got the following error

> MyOtherCustomeViewModel does not contain the definition for BusinessAddress.

I tried to cast `(MyCustomViewModel)obj.AddressObject` which has the BusinessAddress property. MyOtherCustomeViewModel is just another inherited class.

The AddressObject is of a different Class.

When I debug the code, if the object does not contain BusinessAddress project, it will throw this error
"Unable to cast objectt of type 'OtherViewModel' to type.

In other scenario, if the BusinessAddress object is loaded to the AddressObject, it will work and is not null.

I am a little confused by the existing code, any help is appreciated.

```
public class MyCustomViewModel : MyOtherCustomeViewModel
{
 public BusinessViewModel BusinessAddress {get;set;}
}

public class MyOtherCustomeViewModel{
{
 /// BusinessAddress  is not here
}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: What is `obj` here? We need more details.

Comment: You can do something like this `(obj.AddressObject as MyCustomViewModel)?.BusinessAddress != null`.